# Electron: process.platform undefined

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-builder

My global variable `process` is not set when my electron app is packaged. It only contains these info: `{"title":"browser","browser":true,"env":{},"argv":[],"version":"","versions":{}}`.

`process` is not manipulated in my code and info like `process.platform` are only available in development mode. I'm using electron-builder (v23.6.0) and electron (v23.1.3).

I found this problem when using electron-updater. This package uses variables like `process.platform` or `process.resourcesPath` so I guess it's not normal that mine is that empty.

Comment: you're accessing `process` in the main process, or where?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution by explicitly importing the 'process' package like so

```
import prcs from 'process'
```

I assumed it would be accessible in the main process without doing that since it's possible in other nodeJS applications. Apparently not.

Comment: This fix issue for me too. Thanks! The strange thing is that in previous electron-react-boilerlate project structure process.platform works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this issue is that you use [node-polyfill-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/Richienb/node-polyfill-webpack-plugin)

it polyfill node.js process global with this short version for the web browser only.
You can try in webpack config to exclude process from polyfilled globals

```
new NodePolyfillPlugin({
            excludeAliases: ['process']
})
```